# Resampling overlap between two lists

Tags: r, random, overlap, resampling

I have two .txt files. Both files are lists of strings with one string per row eg.

```
GRIM1
PHOXA2
SLITRK4
```

Both text files are ~ 20,000 rows long. I want to randomly sample 500 strings from file 1 and 700 strings from file 2.
Then I want to count the number of strings that overlap both these subsets.
Then I want to repeat this process 100 times and calculate the min, max and mean number of strings that overlap these subsets from the 100 resamplings.

I was trying to adapt some code that used to worked for similar tasks but I get an error:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
> cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

This code was:

```
listA <- read.csv(file="file1.txt", header=F)
listB <- read.csv(file="file2.txt", header=F)

listA <- as.character(listA) # to check that you really have a vector of gene names #maybe you have to do: listA <- as.character(listA)
listB <- as.character(listB) 

res <- rep(NA, 100) 
genesToDraw <- 500 # how many to select 
genesToDraw2 <- 700 # if you want to take different number from second list

for(i in 1:length(res)){

drawA <- sample(x=listA, size=genesToDraw, replace=FALSE)
drawB <- sample(x=listB, size=genesToDraw2, replace=FALSE) # or size=genesToDraw2

res[i] <- length(intersect(drawA, drawB))
}

hist(res, breaks=20)
table(res)
max(res)
sum(res > 5) # how often i
```

Thanks in advance for your help and please let me know if I should clarify.

In response to comments when I run dput(listA) and dput(listB) after the as.character part of the code I get a bunch of comma seperated numbers as output. Here is a subset:

```
1100, 4576, 7394, 1343, 4997, 13807, 1233, 9580, 15254, 10466, 3333, 622, 11177, 4067, 4800, 7592, 5363, 9646, 11213, 14314, 2475, 8389, \n12559, 12808, 5248, 10423, 7856, 12976, 9695, 1674, 2090, 9369, 12089, 13952, 1218, 7966, 6949, 4088, 623, 4768, 2002, 11776, 14710, 5502, 6212, 7300, 2123, 7194, 2128, 1683, 14987, 4491, 2672, 10275, 9424, 997, 15506, 14307, 2644, 11508, 9272, 5107, 10146, 11693, 1802, 652, 13073, 4268, 5435, 718, 4845
```

Best regards,

Rubal

Comment: what is the output of `length(listA)` and `length(listB)`?

Comment: check the class of listA and listB.  the first argument for sample needs to be a vector or integer, and is most likely a data frame here.  The error is saying the number of items in x is less than the number of samples you want to take, which is not allowed when replace=FALSE

Comment: the class is a character.

Comment: And yes length of lists is 1. That must be it. So I should convert them to vectors? If I convert them to integers how will I check for overlap, won't the integers represent their line number rather than the strings themselves?

Comment: @user964689 can you run dput(listA) and dput(listB) after the as.character calls and post those results in your question?

Comment: Yes added to question as requested

Comment: @user964689 how about this, can you make two new txt files, say with only 20 rows each, and then post the entire dput for both lists?  I'm just looking for something I can reproduce.  On another note, looks like you're getting a bunch of numbers where you expected strings!

Comment: @user964689 edited my above comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62682/discussion-between-dmt-and-user964689).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed, first since you are expecting strings, set the stringsAsFactors flag to false in the read.csv calls so you don't mess with factors

```
listA <- read.csv(file="file1.txt", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
listB <- read.csv(file="file2.txt", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now you will have two dataframes, each with one column, of character objects.  the sample function requires vectors, so we can convert our one column dataframes to vectors via

```
listA<-listA[,1]
listB<-listB[,1]
```

and that should get your code to run!